# Rearranging multiple rows of a dataframe on big data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, insert, delete-row, rbind

I am relatively new in R. I have a dataframe `test` that looks like this:

```
PMID    # id
LID
STAT
MH
RN
OT
PST     # cue
LID
STAT
MH
PMID    # id
OT
PST     # cue
LID
DEP
RN
PMID    # id
PST     # cue
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
PMID    # id
LID
STAT
MH
RN
OT
PST     # cue
PMID    # id
LID
STAT
MH
OT
PST     # cue
PMID    # id
LID
DEP
RN
PST     # cue
```

Basically, I want the entries that follow PMID to be for that particular PMID, which is the case for the first PMID. However, after the first PMID, the PMID is nestled randomly in between its entries. However, each PMID ends with a PST, so I want the subsequent PMIDs after the first one to be moved to the location after the previous PST's location. I have two dataframes that contain the index location of each PMID and of PST. So for instance, for PMID, df `a_new` contains

```
1 
11
17
```

and for PST, df `b` contains

```
7
13
18
```

This is what I have tried, but because I have over 24 million rows, it didn't finish running after hours and when I stopped it, my dataframe had not changed:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test))
{    
  if (i %in% a_new$X1) # if it's a PMID
  {
    entry <- match(i, a_new$X1) # find entry index of PMID
    if (entry != 1) # as long as not first row from a_new (that's corrected)
    {
      r <- b[i, 1] # row of PST
      test <- rbind(test[1:r, ], test[entry, 1], test[-(1:r), ])
      test <- test[-c(i+1), ] # remove duplicate PMID
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `rbind` would be extremely inefficient in this situation. Please advise.

Comment: `test` does not look like a `data.frame` : it has no column name and no row number

Comment: it's 24 million observations/rows and 1 column

Comment: I don't know how to add column and row numbers in stackoverflow (without it being manual)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

dat <- fread("Origcol
             PMID
             LID
             STAT
             MH
             RN
             OT
             PST     
             LID
             STAT
             MH
             PMID    
             OT
             PST     
             LID
             DEP
             RN
             PMID   
             PST")

dat[, old_order := 1:.N]
pst_index <- c(0, which(dat$Origcol == "PST"))
dat[, grp := unlist(lapply(1:(length(pst_index)-1), 
                           function(x) rep(x, 
                                           times = (pst_index[x+1] - pst_index[x]))))]
dat[, Origcol := factor(Origcol, levels = c("PMID", "LID", "STAT", 
                                            "MH", "RN", "OT", 
                                            "DEP", "PST"))]
dat[order(grp, Origcol)]
```

Results in:

```
    Origcol old_order grp
 1:    PMID         1   1
 2:     LID         2   1
 3:    STAT         3   1
 4:      MH         4   1
 5:      RN         5   1
 6:      OT         6   1
 7:     PST         7   1
 8:    PMID        11   2
 9:     LID         8   2
10:    STAT         9   2
11:      MH        10   2
12:      OT        12   2
13:     PST        13   2
14:    PMID        17   3
15:     LID        14   3
16:      RN        16   3
17:     DEP        15   3
18:     PST        18   3
```

The benefit of this is data.table is doing a lot of operations by reference, and should be fast once you scale up the size. You said you have 14 million rows, lets try it out. Generate some synthetic data of that size:

```
dat_big <- data.table(Origcol = c("PMID", "LID", "STAT", "MH", "RN", "OT", "PST"))
dat_big_add <- rbindlist(lapply(1:10000, 
                                function(x) data.table(Origcol = c(sample(c("PMID", "LID", "STAT", 
                                                                            "MH", "RN", "OT")), 
                                                                   "PST"))))
dat_big <- rbindlist(list(dat_big, 
                          dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, 
                          dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, 
                          dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, 
                          dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add, dat_big_add))

dat <- rbindlist(list(dat_big, dat_big, dat_big, dat_big, dat_big,
                      dat_big, dat_big, dat_big, dat_big, dat_big))
```

We now have:

```
          Origcol
       1:    PMID
       2:     LID
       3:    STAT
       4:      MH
       5:      RN
      ---        
14000066:    STAT
14000067:      MH
14000068:      OT
14000069:    PMID
14000070:     PST
```

Apply the same code as above:

```
dat[, old_order := 1:.N]
pst_index <- c(0, which(dat$Origcol == "PST"))
dat[, grp := unlist(lapply(1:(length(pst_index)-1), 
                           function(x) rep(x, 
                                           times = (pst_index[x+1] - pst_index[x]))))]
dat[, Origcol := factor(Origcol, levels = c("PMID", "LID", "STAT", 
                                            "MH", "RN", "OT", 
                                            "DEP", "PST"))]
dat[order(grp, Origcol)]
```

We now get:

```
          Origcol old_order     grp
       1:    PMID         1       1
       2:     LID         2       1
       3:    STAT         3       1
       4:      MH         4       1
       5:      RN         5       1
      ---                          
14000066:    STAT  14000066 2000010
14000067:      MH  14000067 2000010
14000068:      RN  14000064 2000010
14000069:      OT  14000068 2000010
14000070:     PST  14000070 2000010
```

How long does it take?

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  "data.table" = {
    dat[, old_order := 1:.N]
    pst_index <- c(0, which(dat$Origcol == "PST"))
    dat[, grp := unlist(lapply(1:(length(pst_index)-1), 
                               function(x) rep(x, 
                                               times = (pst_index[x+1] - pst_index[x]))))]
    dat[, Origcol := factor(Origcol, levels = c("PMID", "LID", "STAT", 
                                                "MH", "RN", "OT", 
                                                "DEP", "PST"))]
    dat[order(grp, Origcol)]
  }, 
  times = 10)
```

And it takes:

```
Unit: seconds
       expr      min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
 data.table 5.755276 5.813267 6.059665 5.87151 6.034506 7.310169    10
```

Under 10 seconds for 14 million rows. It took a lot longer to generate the test data.

Comment: wow, thank you for such a thorough answer! your explanation looks very promising. however, while running the `test[, grp:= unlist....` line, I ran across this error: `Error in rep(x, time = (pst_index[x + 1] - pst_index[x])) : 
  invalid 'times' argument`

Comment: Is there something different about your `test` dataset? Does it fail on your computer copying my code as is?

Comment: oh, your code works just fine copying as is. my actual dataset has some rows that start the same (you'll see what I mean in the next sentence) and are subsequent to each other. and also, each row isn't just one word - for instance, `PMID - 234254` or `MH - human` but I don't know why that would affect the error. I changed my dataframe to data.table using `setDT(df)` after seeing your code...is that the appropriate response?

Comment: oh, I didn't appropriately change the variable name (where you used Origcol)...let me try changing that (update: still hasn't worked yet)

Comment: my pst_index is 0 for some reason...oh I see...I will need to do a partial search for PST only, not an exact search since that line is `PST - ppublish` or something else...

Comment: What is your line that is equivalent to `pst_index <- c(0, which(dat$Origcol == "PST"))`? You will need to change `dat` to the name of your data.table and `Origcol` to your column name.

Comment: `pst_index` should end up being the same as your df `b`, other than having a 0 at the start (to make the indexing easier in the next step).

Comment: okay the code runs without errors. however, the final dataframe/datatable contains all NAs where the data used to be (in the first column). the last two columns look fine and this is because my dataframe's rows are all characters that, as mentioned, actually have other characters following it. so without running the last line, all the columns are present. but for the purpose I need this for, I think I can manage from this step (unordered but have a grp associated...I need to eventually convert into long data so this can work). thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an indexing method using `which`.

```
# get positions of PST, the final value
endSpot <- which(temp == "PST")
# increment to get the desired positions of the PMID
# (dropping final value as we don't need to change it)
startSpot <- head(endSpot + 1, -1)
# get the current positions of the PMID, except the first one
PMIDSpot <- tail(which(temp == "PMID"), -1)
```

Now, use these indices to swap rows

```
temp[c(startSpot, PMIDSpot), ] <- temp[c(PMIDSpot, startSpot), ]
```

This returns (I added a row position variable called count to keep track).

```
temp
     V1 count
1  PMID     1
2   LID     2
3  STAT     3
4    MH     4
5    RN     5
6    OT     6
7   PST     7
8  PMID    11
9  STAT     9
10   MH    10
11  LID     8
12   OT    12
13  PST    13
14 PMID    17
15  DEP    15
16   RN    16
17  LID    14
18  PST    18
```

**data**

```
temp <-
structure(list(V1 = c("PMID", "LID", "STAT", "MH", "RN", "OT", 
"PST", "LID", "STAT", "MH", "PMID", "OT", "PST", "LID", "DEP", 
"RN", "PMID", "PST"), count = 1:18), .Names = c("V1", "count"
), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame")
```